# Julia Plots; how can I individually plot coupled equations graphs?

Tags: plot, julia, differential-equations

I am learning Julia, specifically how to solve coupled differential equations. I am looking at the document page for differential equations and have taken this code from it:

```
using DifferentialEquations


function lorenz(du,u,p,t)
    du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
    du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
    du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0;0.0;0.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz,u0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob)
using Plots; plot(sol)
```

So this plots the u[1],u[2] and u[3] on the same graph, however I wanted to know how I could plot 3 individual graphs for u[1], u[2] and u[3]? This isn't useful here, but for mathematical differential equations, it would be useful to plot the component properties on different graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plotting commands [are documented on this page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/plot.html). You can see that `vars` allows you to choose the variables you wish to plot. So to make some subplots, you can do things like:

```
p1 = plot(sol, vars=1)
p2 = plot(sol, vars=2)
p3 = plot(sol, vars=3)
plot(p1,p2,p3,layout=(3,1))
```

If you want to plot all of the variables, a nice little trick described by @hesham_EE is you can just give a layout and it will automatically split it into different plots:

```
plot(sol, layout = (3,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one plot as a grid:

```
plot(sol, layout = (3,1))
```

Or, if you prefer, you can plot each one in its own plot. For example, to plot the 1st, you can do:

```
plot(sol[1,:])
```